# WSS 3.0 and CKEDITOR

Tags: sharepoint, ckeditor

I wonder if it is possible to integrate the CKEditor with sharepoint (WSS 3.0). Could it be possible with Visual Studio and deploying such as a Web Part??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with **CKEditor for SharePoint**:
http://ckeditor.com/sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to host web pages/web parts that use the CKEditor.  If you are looking to use the CKEditor instead of a normal SharePoint text field for editing that might be a little tougher.  Your best bet for the second would be to create your own Field type and corresponding control that uses the CKEditor.

Hope that helps.